# Mistake in my query can't figure what it is

Tags: php, sql, select

I've been executing this sql code, but my database returns me `NULL`'s after the `left join`. Any ideas on what may be happening?

This is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `fotoalbum` LEFT JOIN `foto`
ON `fotoalbum`.`fotoalbum_id` = `foto`.`fotoalbum`
```

And the table information:

```
Fotoalbum rows: ID, Name
Foto rows: ID, Name, Path, album_id
```

Comment: Sorry was editing realising it as you said it.

Comment: nulls? Or does the query fail? I suspect the latter.

Comment: What error did you get in `mysqli_error()`?

Comment: None, when I do inspect element, at my img src="is empty" while on a plain select from it works, so it had to be my query I figured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM fotoalbum LEFT JOIN foto ON foto.album_id=fotoalbum.ID`

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but then I would expect the query to fail instead of returning null values for the left joined table...

Comment: It did indeed fail :/

Comment: So, does the query in my answer (a) fail, (b) return no rows, (c) return rows with nulls, or (d) return rows with data?  If a, b, c, please post the exact table structure. For MySQL, that would be: `SHOW CREATE TABLE foto` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE fotoalbum`.

Comment: foto  CREATE TABLE `foto` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Naam` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 `Omschrijving` text NOT NULL,
 `Pad` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

As for the other

fotoalbum  CREATE TABLE `fotoalbum` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Naam` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: I'm so sorry for the mess I don't know how to properly show it on stackoverflow :S Also to answer your question it gave me NULL not fail.

Comment: You can edit your original post ("OP") and add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output there.  Make sure you use the "code" style so it appears in a block. (Check the preview below to see.)  That said, the query I've given looks like it will work with your schema.  Run it from the mysql command line and check it returns results.  Then check your PHP code for errors.

Comment: But I did run the SQL in the database to test and it returns me NULL's right after the Left Join before it it gives me the information (from fotoalbum) Thanks for the tip about editing by the way.

Comment: Hey thanks for your SQL I changed the LEFT Into a RIGHT and it worked.